# C# MWMCR:EvaluateFunction error

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, out-of-memory

I am using some matlab functions in c#. When I convert a function to dll, I have two dll. One is Entropy.dll and other one is EntropyNative.dll.

If I use the Entropy.dll I must install the matlab compiler runtime (MCR) to the target computer because it needs MWArray class and it only works with MCR. However I do not want to install MCR to target computer so I have tried to use the EntropyNative.dll because it takes `Object` instead `MWArray` as parameter. Thus I do not need to install MCR to each computer. However when I use the native dll, `MWMCR:EvaluateFunction error.` occurs. That means out of memory exception. File size and functions are same but why this error occurs when I use the native dll?

This (Entropy.dll) one works and error not occurs.

```
MWNumericArray arr1 = null;
Entropy ent = new Entropy(); //Matlab function.
while(true)
{
     double[] arraySegment = new double[window];
     arr1=arraySegment;
     MWArray function1Result = ent.function1(arr1);
     MWArray function2Result = ent.function2(arr1);
     arr1=null;
}
```

If I use EntropyNative.dll out of memory error occurs

```
Entropy ent = new Entropy();
while(true)
{
     double[] arraySegment = new double[window];
     double function1Result = ent.function1(arraySegment);
     double function2Result = ent.function2(arraySegment);
}
```

I want to use Native dll so how can I eliminate this error? I tried to force GarbageCollector but it does not help me. Also I have tried `ent.WaitForFiguresToDie()` and `ent.Dispose()`.

> ent.WaitForFiguresToDie(): 
>   This method will cause a MATLAB figure window to behave as a modal
>   dialog box.  The method will not return until all the figure windows
>   associated with this component have been closed.

Comment: If the file size of EntropyNative.dll and Entropy.dll are the same, are you sure that they are indeed different?

Comment: They are same. However Entropy.function uses MWArray but EntropyNative.function uses Object as parameter.

Comment: But if they're implemented the same way, then I would assume that they both require the MCR and you need to install and initialize it. Getting rid of the MCR requires a completely independent implementation (or a library that was built using the matlab coder).

Comment: I removed MCR and ran the program for a small amount of data. It works. Fine. Also i realize that if I only calculates one function it does not gives error. I will try to calculate them one by one. I hope it works.